# Running a function in a python file in Git Bash

Tags: python, git-bash

I have a python file called lab01.py and it contains two functions

```
def both_positive(a, b):
     return a > 0 and b > 0

def sum_digits(x):
     """
     Sum all the digits of x.
     """
     ans = 0
     num = str(x)
     for ele in num:
         ans += eval(ele)
return ans
```

I need to print out the output of sum_digits(x) function in Git Bash. Here is my command line I entered

```
$ cd ~/desktop/programming/lab01
$ python -c 'import lab01; print lab01.sum_digits(10)'
```

The first command line runs successfully but I got a SyntaxError for the second line. Any help?
[image]

Comment: oarens for the print function call`()`

Comment: @Alan Hoover  Thanks for the help! Do you mean $python -c 'import lab01; print (lab01.sum_digits(10))'

Comment: @hck007 `$python -c 'import lab01; print(lab01.sum_digits(10))`

Comment: Why use `eval()` here? Wouldn't a simple `int()` call do the trick? Also, please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the parenthesis to the print function:

```
$ python -c 'import lab01; print(lab01.sum_digits(10))'
```

The syntax without the parenthesis is for python 2, and your Git Bash emulator should be running python 3 if that's what you installed on your computer.

Python 2 print statement was replaced with a function (hence the parenthesis) in Python 3. So you need to use `print()`.

edit: also, if that's the code you are using for the lab01.py file, your return seems to be outside the function block.